# How to enable the default "product rating review" form in product page,In Megento 1.9

Tags: php, jquery, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to enable the default rating-review form on my product page. I problem I'm facing is the "Be the first to review the product" is appearing but the link is not working.
[This is my product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bniCu.png)
when I first time clicks on the link, the link gets redirect to another page(URL: localhost/Magento/review/product/list/id/28/#review-form)something like.
[this is my second page and again when I clicked on the link nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGHST.png)

**REQUIRED CHANGES THAT I DID**

In admin panel, Enable the product rating.And "Catalog->rating and review->manage rating" there i gave the sort order to"value,prica and quakity".

**IN BACKEND**

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span class="nav nav-tab "><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked your site indexes? That's normally where I go first if links aren't working as expected

Comment: yes, I checked the issue is not from there.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instructions:

**Step1 :-** Go to app-> design-> frontend-> Your package name(base/rwd)-> Your theme(default...)-> layout-> review.xml

**Step2 :-** Paste below code to review.xml and refresh product view page. go to tab, now you can see review form.

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: it works like, review form is now displayed below the link(be the first to review this product) and after submitting it redirects to cart page & reviews not even gets submitted, I check on admin panel.

Comment: But redirecting think is fine. I can change that but the thing is I want that review form after clicked on the link.

Comment: Actually, I'm confused I don't know why the link redirects to this page(URL: localhost/Magento/review/product/list/id/28/#review-form).
Could you pls tell me what I should write in <a href="<?php,......?>" so that it redirects to the form that is now visible under the link, as I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: please put current url with #customer-reviews as like this

<a href="<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl() ?>#customer-reviews"><?php echo $this->__('Add Your Review') ?></a>